# Sizing Images in tableview cell swift

Tags: swift, tableview

I've been trying to get all of the tableView images to show as the same size with no luck in swift. Right now they are all different sizes. I've have tried many options, nothing seems to work. Anyone see the problem? Thanks in advance.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell = myTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel.text = colleges[indexPath.row].name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = colleges[indexPath.row].location
    cell.imageView.image = colleges[indexPath.row].image
    cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)


    return cell
}
```

Comment: look into either subclassing `UITableViewCell` and overriding `-layoutSubviews` or overriding `-didDisplayCellForRowAtIndexPath`